# How to run Pub.build() in Dart 2

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-webui

In Dart 1.x, there was a command, that you could trigger e.g. from grinder.dart. But this line works no longer:

```
Pub.build();
```

How can I replace it and run build command of my web app from Dart code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling webdev build directly

Answer (score 2):

`pub build` is no longer supported in Dart 2.

You need to run `pub run build_runner build`.

See https://webdev.dartlang.org/dart-2

I'm not sure if there are new APIs for Grinder, though.

Comment: Well, that's what I read on every single manual page, but there is no Grinder (etc.) manual, that's why I asked. Or sould I just run `Process.run('pub run build_runner build', runInShell: true)`? (creepy workaround)

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/google/grinder.dart/issues/327